# How do you set the page description in a flutter web app?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I know you can set the title of your web app with this code:

```
MaterialApp(
  title: 'App Title',
  ...
```

But is it possible to set the description meta tag the same way?

By default mine is showing:

```
<meta name="description" content="A new Flutter project.">
```

Comment: Just change the description to what you want?

Comment: @ChristopherMoore I had pulled the meta tag from the browser, I didn't realize that it was as simple as changing the static file. But there is still an open question for me: Is it possible to set a dynamic description?

Answer (score 1):

The solution for my ended up being incredibly simple - I just needed to edit the file located at `web/index.html`.

I'm still not sure how one would set the description dynamically - but that's probably only a case for the select few that are trying to serve a flutter app that can be read by crawlers.

Comment: If there was someething that would influence the metadata for a flutter web app, I'm sure it'd have to be related to the Semantic class, which also provides voiceover support for widgets.  You can also use the JS Interop with flutter web, and manipulate the dom as you wish... even to the point of ruining your app. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the tag meta

```
<meta name="description" content="Your description here...">
```

in the folder web and file index.html
web/index.html